# How to restore libvirt network default configure file?

Tags: libvirt

I accidently deleted the `/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml`. How to restore it? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On some distros you can find the original master in `/usr/share/libvirt/networks`. Alternatively it is in [GIT upsteam](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/master/src/network/default.xml.in).

Once you have the file, simply run as root:

```bash
virsh net-define default.xml
virsh net-start default
virsh net-autostart default  # if you want it to run on boot
```

Comment: That link is broken. Here is the link that worked for me https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/master/src/network/default.xml

Comment: The link changed to https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/master/src/network/default.xml.in